# How to configure Play not to listen on jpda port when using Heroku?

Tags: heroku, playframework

I'm getting this error when trying to start my play app on Heroku:

```
heroku[web.1]: Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 8000, should be 46275 (see environment variable PORT)
```

I think this is play trying to listen on the jpda port, which Heroku prohibits. My Procfile looks like this:

```
web:    play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS
```

My PLAY_OPTS in heroku config looks like this:

```
PLAY_OPTS           => --%prod -Dprecompiled=true
```

In my application.conf, mode is set like this:

```
application.mode=dev
```

What do I need to do to get this to deploy? Do I need to somehow disable the jpda port, or set the mode to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application.conf file you need a line to define prod mode

```
%prod.application.mode=prod
```

Try locally to run play run --%prod to be sure in this mode you don't open a jpda port.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is a good way to do this in `dev` mode.  In `play-1.2.3/framework/pym/play/application.py` you can see that it always starts the debug stuff when in `dev` mode:

```
    if self.readConf('application.mode') == 'dev':
        if not self.play_env["disable_check_jpda"]: self.check_jpda()
        java_args.append('-Xdebug')
        java_args.append('-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=%s,server=y,suspend=n' % self.jpda_port)
        java_args.append('-Dplay.debug=yes')
```